# JOLT shift transformation: filter by inner value of a property (not the name) - only some properties

Tags: java, json, tree, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using Jolt transformation looking for some input here.
I am trying to filter by the inner value of the attribute.

**My goal is to get an array that contains only the items with the typeName 'xx'. But not all the item object, only some of the fields**

```json
{
  "id": "11_1",
  "action": "add",
  "payment": {
    "paied": true,
    "coin": "dollar"
  },
  "type": {
    "id": "11_1_xx",
    "typeName": "xx"
  },
  "details": {
    "place": {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "xx"
    },
    "status": {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "xx"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my input and expected output:

*Input*:

```json
{
  "id": 11,
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "11_1",
      "action": "add",
      "payment": {
        "paied": true,
        "coin": "dollar"
      },
      "type": {
        "id": "11_1_xx",
        "typeName": "xx",
        "typeGroup": "xx",
        "typeValue": "xx"
      },
      "details": {
        "place": {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "xx"
        },
        "status": {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "xx"
        },
        "reason": {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "xx"
        }
      },
      "item": [
        {
          "id": "11_1_1",
          "action": "add",
          "payment": {
            "paied": true,
            "coin": "dollar"
          },
          "type": {
            "id": "11_1_1_zz",
            "typeName": "zz",
            "typeGroup": "zz",
            "typeValue": "zz"
          },
          "details": {
            "place": {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "xx"
            },
            "status": {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "xx"
            },
            "reason": {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "xx"
            }
          },
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_1_1",
              "action": "add",
              "payment": {
                "paied": true,
                "coin": "NIS"
              },
              "type": {
                "id": "11_1_1_1_xx",
                "typeName": "xx",
                "typeGroup": "xx",
                "typeValue": "xx"
              },
              "details": {
                "place": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "xx"
                },
                "status": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "xx"
                },
                "reason": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "xx"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "11_1_2",
          "action": "add",
          "payment": {
            "paied": false,
            "coin": "dollar"
          },
          "type": {
            "id": "11_1_2_xx",
            "typeName": "xx",
            "typeGroup": "xx",
            "typeValue": "xx"
          },
          "details": {
            "place": {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "xx"
            },
            "status": {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "xx"
            },
            "reason": {
              "id": "123",
              "name": "xx"
            }
          },
          "item": [
            {
              "id": "11_1_2_1",
              "action": "add",
              "payment": {
                "paied": false,
                "coin": "NIS"
              },
              "type": {
                "id": "11_1_2_1_zz",
                "typeName": "zz",
                "typeGroup": "zz",
                "typeValue": "zz"
              },
              "details": {
                "place": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "xx"
                },
                "status": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "xx"
                },
                "reason": {
                  "id": "123",
                  "name": "xx"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Expected output*:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "11_1",
    "action": "add",
    "payment": {
      "paied": true,
      "coin": "dollar"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": "11_1_xx",
      "typeName": "xx"
    },
    "details": {
      "place": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "xx"
      },
      "status": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "xx"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_1_1",
    "action": "add",
    "payment": {
      "paied": true,
      "coin": "NIS"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": "11_1_1_1_xx",
      "typeName": "xx"
    },
    "details": {
      "place": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "xx"
      },
      "status": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "xx"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "11_1_2",
    "action": "add",
    "payment": {
      "paied": false,
      "coin": "dollar"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": "11_1_2_xx",
      "typeName": "xx"
    },
    "details": {
      "place": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "xx"
      },
      "status": {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "xx"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Can you please help me to write a simple spec that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following explained spec

```json
[
  {
    // Determine all key-value pairs partitioned under the main value and type.typeValue combinations 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item": {
        "*": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "item": {
                "*": {
                  "type": {
                    "@(1,id)": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).id", //traverse } character twice in order to reach the main id of the object
                    "@(1,action)": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).action",
                    "*": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&" // &1 replicates "type" key, & does the leaf value
                  },
                  "*": "@(1,id).@(1,type.typeName).&"
                }
              },
              "type": {
                "@(1,id)": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).id",
                "@(1,action)": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).action",
                "*": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&"
              },
              "*": "@(1,id).@(1,type.typeName).&"
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "@(1,id)": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).id",
            "@(1,action)": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).action",
            "*": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&"
          },
          "*": "@(1,id).@(1,type.typeName).&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Filter out by the desired value(in this case it's "xx") 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "xx": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Get rid of same repeating components of id and action arrays
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "ONE",
        "action": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Get rid of undesired attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": {
          "typeGroup": "",
          "typeValue": ""
        },
        "det*": {
          "reason": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: HI @barbaros-Özhan, thanks a lot!!, little Q plz: there is any way to choose which fields I want to map, not to map all the fields and then remove the unnecessary? in my example: map the details.place and details.status and not all the details object and then remove the details.reason and the same for the fields in the type object?

Comment: Hi @Michal , it's also possible no to use a **remove** spec. , but I think using **remove** is practical in this case. As an example; you need to individually write one by one `"id": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&", "typeName": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&"` in order to replace the line `"*": "@(2,id).@(1,typeName).&1.&"` nested within the `type` object. It goes on like that for all the desired attributes to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson*. Function `map()` build a new ObjectNode. Function `field()` modify the current ObjectNode and can be used to remove fields. The transformation statement is short and easy to understand.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(inputJSON);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "cumulateCollect(" +
    "    [type.typeName='xx']" +              // filter
    "        .field(type.map(id, typeName)" + // need "type.id" and "type.typeName"
    "              ,details.field(reason:)" + // remove "details.reason"
    "              ,item:)" +                 // remove "item"
    "   ,item)");                             // next round
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```